# How make animation for two element. one element fallow anouther with delay and hide him

Tags: jquery, css, animation, setinterval, keyframe

I have two element. They should move with delay. One element move after another and cover him. Elemnt move one after anouther, but not cover previous element. Css inside classes same - different class name and one second element add delay.
JS on both element.

```
    $('main>.container').append('<a href="" class="icon-featured roll-in-left"` target="_blank" title="">' +
        '<img src="icon.png" alt="">' +
        '</a>');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.icon-featured').removeClass('roll-in-left');
    },1000);
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.icon-featured').toggleClass('roll-in-left');

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.icon-featured').removeClass('roll-in-left');
        },1000)

    }, 14000);


$('main>.container').append('<a href="" class="icon-featured1 roll-in-left1" target="_blank" title="">' +
        '<img src="header_menu.png" alt="">' +
        '</a>');
   setTimeout(function () {
        $('.icon-featured1').removeClass('roll-in-left1');

    },20000);
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.icon-featured1').toggleClass('roll-in-left1');

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.icon-featured1').removeClass('roll-in-left1');

        },20000)
    }, 16000);
```

CSS animation.

```
.roll-in-left {-webkit-animation: roll-in-left  1s ease-out both;animation: roll-in-left 1s ease-out both;}
@-webkit-keyframes roll-in-left {0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-800px) rotate(540deg);transform:translateX(-800px) rotate(540deg);opacity: 0;}100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);opacity: 1;}
```

}

Comment: welcome, my friend. make a reproducible example, or paste the html code here, pls.